# Deploying intellij maven project to azure web apps using FTP, getting a 500 server error

Tags: java, maven, azure, intellij-idea, azure-web-app-service

I have been trying to deploy a intellij java project to Azure Web Apps using FTP. The project is a simple REST api using Jetty and Maven.
Running the api locally works fine.

I build a .war artifact, using intellij, of the project.
[.war artifact build in intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DosLs.png)

And used FileZilla to deploy it to an Azure Web App [FileZilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkDj6.png)

[The azure settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtoBa.png)

But when I try to access my azure app, just by going to the URL (in browser and using postman with a simple GET request) I get an error 500 server error.

HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /. Reason:

```
Server Error
```

Caused by:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:119)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Jsr199JavaCompiler.compile(Jsr199JavaCompiler.java:208)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:384)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1539)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Powered by Jetty://

When I try to access my endpoint, I receive an Error 404 Not Found.

HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /login. Reason:

```
Not Found
```

Powered by Jetty://

[Code with paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoETM.png)

I am sort of at my wits end here. Does anyboy know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't change the application settings in the portal,you need to change the settings to fit you application you just deployed,you need to set the java version to what you want.
[reference this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD78S.png)
You can also change the Virtual applications and directories to "site\wwwwroot\webapps" to reduce the risk of fail.Hope it benefit.